# Using two Id's is good idea?

Tags: sql, database-design, identification

Example of table:

```
------------------------------------
| Id | ItemId | Description | Price |
------------------------------------
```

A two Id's (`Id` and `ItemId`) are both unique and generated automatically. Difference between them is that first Id(`Id`) used as classic Id for in-table identification and the second Id (`ItemId`) used as item identification field and it's resistant to table cleanup (when performing classic Id's reset) and migration.

That's good idea or not? And why? Please explain.

Comment: Whats *classic Id's reset* ?

Comment: When we rearrange rows, recounting them Id's again. 
Also, maybe this useful when we transfer data between tables/lists and do not want to loose original identification codes.

Comment: that's generally a bad idea.  Will you be doing that to multi-million row tables and associated FK's? I don't think so.

Comment: What is bad? Rearranging or double Ids?

Comment: Why can't you just use ItemId as the primary key ? If you referenced an Item in a different table which value would you post as a foreign key, Id or ItemId. It looks like you don't need Id at all.

Comment: Hi arman. Just a non-related information, it's best practice to add @username to your comment. With this, username will get notification in their inbox regarding your comment. Ex: "@Mitch Wheat What is bad? etc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very common practice to implement (at least) two keys per table: a *surrogate key*, typically used for referential integrity purposes (`Id` in your example) and a *natural key* - AKA *domain key* or *business key* - used as an identifier in the business domain (presumably `ItemId` in your example).

It isn't universally a good idea to use surrogates. You should decide on a case by case basis the intended purpose and advantage of each key you want to implement. Don't assume one design pattern fits all. As a very general rule some good criteria for choosing and designing keys are the familiarity, simplicity and stability of the key attribute(s). Aside from that, business rules should determine what keys you need. Have as many keys as necessary to model the business domain accurately and maintain data integrity.

On a point of terminology, don't use the word *Id* if you really mean *key*. Id is far too ambiguous and overloaded. In relational/SQL databases rows are identified by keys. Id is ok for column names but not the right way to describe a table design or ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually totally depends on your requirement. If your requirement say’s you gonna need identity then go for it ideally it’s not a good habit to use ID columns, It does not make sense at the data level, and it’s hard to have ID column as foreign key. One is advised to use Identity column only in case you don’t have natural primary key in you data.